# How to clear entries of TextFields and set them to default with the click of a button?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a UI using Google's Material-UI and React. After creating a page that needs input from Material-ui's TextFields, I need to reset the fields on the click of a material-ui button. Can someone guide me on how to implement this?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const  Page = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Location > Child Location</h3>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-md m-b-15">
          <div>
            <p>Some paragraph</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md m-b-15">
          <p>Name of the text field</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-b-15">
          <TextField
            hintText="Text field..."
            fullWidth={true}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   );
};
```

The updated code after the suggestions:

```
import React, from 'react';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

export default class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      data: {
        firstName: '',
      }
    }

    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
  }

  handleReset() {
    this.setState({
      data: {
        firstName: '',
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <TextField
          hintText="Text field..."
          fullWidth
          value={data.firstName}
        />

        <FlatButton label="Reset values" onClick={this.handleReset} />
      </div>
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You just need to make a call to a function and in that function set the value of textfield as null or empty. Or if you are using state to fill the TextField you need to reset the state on that function call.

Comment: @ShubhamJain i was thinking to use state in fact, but even if i have many text fields, i should just use the same state for all of them right?

Comment: Yes you should use same state if all the textfields do the same task. But if they are not dependent then you must initialise new state for each TextField else how would you keep track of which state is corresponding to which TextField

Comment: Line 1: there's an extra comma. `render`, remove both `...`

Comment: @HemersonCarlin Done. The bind error still persists.

Comment: Which react version are you using?

Comment: @HemersonCarlin 15.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are storing those values somewhere (for example state).

```js
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      data: {
        firstName: '',
      }
    }
    
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      data: {
        firstName: event.target.value
      }
    })
  }
  
  handleReset() {
    this.setState({
      data: {
        firstName: '',
      }
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state
    
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={data.firstName} />
        
        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset values</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This helps me very much, thanks! But while i am trying to render this, my page doesn't load at all now.

Comment: At first it said that it couldn't read value 'undefined' from data. But after reloading it again, it doesn't show any error, but the page is just blank. Also i had to rewrite the syntax of the handleClick() to: `handleClick = () => {}` because it could not be compiled for some reason.

Comment: I don't recommend using arrow functions for event handlers due to performance issues. Are you binding 'handleClick' in the constructor? That should work.

Comment: Maybe the syntax needed for the specific component in Material's Design cannot be overwritten by adding ours? [TextField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field)

Comment: I had some mistakes with my brackets, and even though i fixed them and now the binding is in the constructor. The page simply keeps loading and shows blank.

Comment: `it couldn't read value 'undefined' ` is something wrong with your `state` (maybe syntax). About " specific component in Material's Design cannot be overwritten" is also not true because I also use material ui :)

Comment: I understand, but still the state syntax is the same as the one you provided up there in your answer. I am even more confused :p

Comment: Try to `console.log` the state on `render` and on `handleReset`.

Comment: I did that, but the console logged just this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: @minus.273 I guess you are doing something else wrong. Check my code snippet. It words exactly as I described :)

Comment: Alright. I will try finding what is wrong. Your help was very much appreciated! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its better to use 'Controlled inputs', which means you save the value in the state/store and pass it to the input, then handle input onChange to update that value, so whenever you want to reset it, you simply clear that state of yours.

the second way might be using the refs to select the DOM input and clear it which isn't the best way.